# Received 38 downvotes on different posts in 4 minutes

Tags: support, down-votes

This is my reputation history right now:

[image: 38 downvotes in a row over the span of 4 minutes]

These are 38 of my highest-voted questions and answers. Looks like I made some enemies. Could moderators handle this, please?

Comment: Moderators cannot see which users have downvoted posts, but the system automatically deals with targeted-voting everyday. Wait for a few hours, and you should get your rep back as the system reverses these :)

Comment: The downvotes should be invalidated sometime tonight by one of the automated bots. That is a very definite "spree". If it's still there tomorrow then I'll contact the team to deal with it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there's a bot for that. Thanks guys!

Comment: The answer on the dupe is relevant here. I believe it's 00:00 UTC that the script runs, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: And it worked. Hurrah! :)

Comment: Someone was upset with you about something.... hmmm!!! Take a moment and read over [Be Nice 101](https://superuser.com/help/be-nice) to ensure you follow those rules and to potentially prevent this from occurring from others in the future that may feel some type a way. Only you can control what you say to others or the language you use when you say it!! I'm sure there's a way to track this if you were keeping some data stats tracking btw.