# I was serial downvoted, please reverse them

Tags: support, down-votes

Today I asked a question, it received two downvotes and was closed. Fine, I deleted it.

But right after that, my five most recent posts were downvoted within one minute, for no reason at all. The downvoter didn't leave a single comment. I suspect the perpetrator to be one person, because each post had only received one downvote. Clearly I was personally targeted, and not my post.

I got five downvotes in a row, if this doesn't qualify as serial downvoting then I don't know what qualifies as serial downvoting. Please reverse that, I know there is a rule to reverse serial downvotes.

As you can see I had 2610 reputation before the serial downvoting, I had only lost 10 reputation, it is tiny compared to my remaining reputation 2600. But I refuse to be a victim, the perpetrator is breaking the rules, and they have to be reprimanded.

Please reverse the serial downvoting.

Comment: Note the downvoter likely has less than 1000 reputation, because one post targeted hasn't received a single upvote, and is a question without answers, so I deleted that post, so you can only see 4 downvotes on my profile now.

Comment: _"if this doesn't qualify as serial downvoting then I don't know what qualifies as serial downvoting"_ - I agree it sounds like you were serial downvoted, but that's _just_ 5 votes. [Received 38 downvotes on different posts in 4 minutes](https://meta.superuser.com/q/13134/194694)

Comment: Serial down votes are normally automatically reverted in 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, it was reversed on its own. Failing which, moderators can't check up on individual votes - had it not been reversed, we'd have escalated it to the community team to handle.